# Can I and how I use datasheet registers to activate scaling up on the RTD2660 display controller?

Tags: arduino, i2c, datasheet, display

I have a chinese display with hdmi driver board using RTD2660 controller chip. I want to use it to mod my Playstation portable with a bigger screen, but the problem is that psp outputs image with black borders around it, and I want to get rid of them. Psp is connected to the screen via av to hdmi converter (borders aren't caused by converter, that's just how psp video output works). In the [datasheet](http://openrtd2662.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/RTD2660_spec.pdf) for RTD2660 in the register map I've found scaling options. Before that, I tried to change resolition in the firmware, but picture just scales to the right and bottom. So now I have an arduino conected by i2c to the chip and [this](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_RTD266X_I2CFlasher) arduino programm for its flasing that already has functions for writing chip's register.
My question is if something is already specified in the firmware (that's on the flash memory), is it even possible to use registers to change it, and how I can do that? If it's adress 34 it should be 0x34, right? But how I write someting to 34-00, 34-01...?

[image]

Comment: what is PSP? ... what kind of an interface does PSP use to output video?

Comment: `If it's adress 34 it should be 0x34, right?` ... it depends on the datasheet author ... do you see addresses in hexadecimal format? ... for example, what address comes before 30? ... or after 39?

Comment: @jsotola, I believe it's hex, after 19 is 1A, after 32 is 33, but then 34-00, 34-01 and so on to 34-11, then comes 35. I edited my question to better understand what I want